# How to balance a dangling node in an AVL tree

Tags: avl-tree

I have a sequence of numbers that are supposed to be placed into an AVL tree:

50, 22, 80, 70, 75, 73

I'm not sure where 73 goes. On my understanding the first balance happens when 75 becomes the right child of 70:

```
  50
 /  \
22   80
    /
  70
    \
    75
```

Thus, 80 is the "unbalanced" node and 70 is the heavy left child. So 70 moves to the left and 80 moves to the right, somehow, like this:

```
      50
     /  \
    22   75
        /  \
       70   80
```

Adding 73, we become unbalanced yet again:

```
      50
     /  \
    22   75
        /  \
       70   80
         \
          73
```

How do I balance this?  I can't just put 73 between 75 and 70, can I?

Answer (score 1):

There is a clearly defined procedure to rebalance an AVL tree.

1. Start from the newly inserted node and move towards root until you find an unbalanced node.
2. Once you are on unbalanced node, determine if its left heavy or right heavy.
3. If it right heavy and its right children is also right heavy, then you will have to perform a single left rotation.
4. If its right heavy and its right children is left heavy (this one matches your case), then you will have to perform right-left double rotation.

there is symmetric procedure for the left heavy case, which I believe you can figure out by yourself.

psudocode for above procedure will look something like this.

```
     z=firstUnbalancedNode();
     if(rightHeavy(z))
     {
          if(rightHeavy(z.rightChild))
          {
               rotateLeft(z.rightChild);
          }
          else
          {
               rotateRight(z.rightChild)
               rotateLeft(z.rightChild)
          }
      }
```

in your case

1. we insert 73 and move up to locate the unbalanced node (if any).
2. we find 50 which is unbalanced.
3. 50 is right heavy and its right children (75) is left heavy which means we will have to perform right-left rotation.

after insertion tree looks like this

```
      50
     /  \
    22   75
        /  \
       70   80
         \
          73
```

now we perform right rotation on 50's right child (75). after this rotation tree looks like this

```
      50
     /  \
    22  70
          \
           75
          /  \
         73   80
```

after this we have to perform a left rotation on 50's right child (70). which will transform the tree to following structure.

```
        70
       /  \
      50   75
     /    /  \
    22   73   80
```

so as you can see there are two basic rotations. left and right.
in some cases a single rotation can do the job while in some other cases you may need to perform both of the rotations.